# Exclude a mesh from Grease Pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

I have a scene with several objects which I'm rendering using Grease Pencil.
I need to exclude one mesh from Grease Pencil, as the mesh is too dense, and Blender freezes if I try to render it.
Is there a way to exclude an object from being rendered from the Grease Pencil line art?

The only thing I can think of is using scenes, and turn off Grease Pencil in the copied scene. Though, I hope there's a more direct control over what object can be affected or excluded.

Comment: You can link all your desired objects to a specific collection and set this as the target of your line art modifier, would that work ?

Comment: Thanks, @Gorgious that works for me!